Container shuffle-opensearch stuck at starting - Error response from daemon:
Stuck at shuffle-opensearch, but the orborus, backend, frontend doesnt have a problementer image description here
1.docker ps
2.docker start shuffle-opensearch

docker logs -f shuffle-opensearch

container might have crashed... so run step 1.
in order (in the folder Shuffle) :
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
docker ps (search for the container)
